# My Game’s In-App Purchasing Doesn’t Function

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-games, cocoonjs, construct-2

I am a Android game developer in Nigeria. My app is in the playstore and it has in-app products. The default price is naturally in Naira, as is my Merchant Bank account.

[Here is the problem: when I try to purchase a product from my game, it gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvHMF.jpg)

My banks subsequently tells me that I have selected the DCC Payment option(Dynamic Currency Conversion) which allows me to pay in Naira which has temporarily restricted on all the cards.

It further tells me to "reattempt the transaction and select the currency of the country you are transacting in".

Now, I do not think this is my bank problem because I have a website hosted on Hostgator, and Hosgator charges 11 dollars from my account every month successfully.

[And when I try to buy stuff from Candy Crush, it does not give any problem. It goes straight ahead and shows me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcQhF.jpg)

I really do not know what the problem is - do I need to get a dollar account for my Google Merchant bank, so that it charges me in dollars and works?

Did anyone in foreign countries have this issue? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: HI,

I don't think the fault is from my phone because it gets rid of the Authentication Required dialog box when I use Candy Crush and just displays the other picture above when I click Purchase, asking me to type my Credit Card number.

Why does mine bring up the error and a regular game doesn't? I think my Settings are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake why we encounter this error is not being able to set the product id. It is important that you set up the in-app product id which should be the same as in the console and activate it.

As stated in [Creating a Product List](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html), you can sell an item using Google Play's in-app billing feature only if the item is listed on an application's product list. And to activate it, access **In-App Products** link in your developer console then check status field.

This related SO post - [Android In-App Billing error You need to sign into your google account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797663/android-in-app-billing-error-you-need-to-sign-into-your-google-account) might help in getting other possible solutions.

Comment: @Ollivander, that's great! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I set the ID of my product incorrectly. Sorted it out now.